# How to fix sink disposal leaking problem?

Tags: sink, kitchen-sink

Since yesterday my sink disposal has kept leaking. I took a video. Please advise how to fix it. Thanks

[Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/cVukf1UWSx5Qz2t88)

Answer (score 1):

That leak is coming from the bottom of the disposal which means the bottom seals or the bottom has rusted out or cracked. 
You'll need to replace it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Rust out is quite common although I did not watch the video. The age would be helpful as this is like saying my truck is leaking oil. Is it a 1980 or 2015 model if you catch my meaning but + jack

Comment: It's a badger... need I say more..